# Displaying concatenated fields in a SQL Server pivot table

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, pivot-table

I have a table of the following structure:

```
Title text
LineNo integer
Key   text
Value text
Units text
```

I created a pivot table to convert row data to column name:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT Title, [Key],[Value] FROM Table1 WHERE [Key] LIKE 'Field_%' AND [LineNo]>0) as Data 
PIVOT(
MAX([Value])
FOR [Key] IN([Field_1],[Field_2],[Field_3])) As Piv
```

Now I'd like to display Units next to each Value. I tried concatenating them but that does not work.

```
SELECT * FROM         
(SELECT     Title, [Key], [Value], [Units] FROM Table1                       
WHERE [Key] LIKE 'Field_%' AND [LineNo] > 0) AS Data 
PIVOT (MAX([Value]) + ' ' + [Units]) FOR [Key] IN ([Field_1],[Field_2],[Field_3])) AS Piv
```

Is there an easy way of doing that without having to create a separate pivot table for Units and joining the two together?

Also some rows do not have units so if units is blanks I do not want to display it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right you I think doing the concatenation in the source might give you the result you want:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Title, [Key], CONCAT([Value], ' ', Units) AS Value 
    FROM Table1 WHERE [Key] LIKE 'Field_%' AND [LineNo] > 0
    ) AS Data 
PIVOT(
MAX([Value])
FOR [Key] IN([Field_1],[Field_2],[Field_3])) AS Piv
```